# DSP board data to Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to build a DSP process in Matlab.

The ADC delivers `uint16` data. This data should be filtered and processed. The filter works in the DSP with fixed point (fract16).

Should a transformation take place if I want to do work with the data Matlab? How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just treat the 16 bit unsigned fractional data as integers and then scale the data to floating point in the range 0.0..+1.0 prior to any processing. E.g.

```
data = data / 65535.0;
```

If the data is actually *signed* fractional (int16) then you would convert it to the range -1.0..+1.0 like this:

```
data = data / 32768.0;
```

Comment: the fractional data are signed and between (-0.99..1). how to do it in this ase?

Comment: OK - you said uint16 in your question - I've added signed fractional conversion to the answer above now.